# class file contains wrong class error while accessing jar file

Tags: java, jar, javac, graalvm

I am trying **to create a JAR file for my two source codes** Serial.java and DBaccess.java.

I am doing this as a learning exercise ,the classes do not do anything,they are dummy classes.

OS - Windows 10

JDK - GraalVM

Listing of my source code.(Serial.java)

```
public class Serial
{

    void open()
    {
        System.out.println("Serial Port Opened - 0");
    }
}
```

Listing of my source code.(DBaccess.java)

```
public class DBaccess
{

    String DBname = "MySerialDB";

    void write()
    {
        System.out.println("Data Written to DB - W");
    }

    void read()
    {
        System.out.println("Data Read from DB - R");
    }
}
```

I have **compiled them to .class files using javac**

- javac DBaccess.java
- javac Serial.java

I  created a folder

```
H:\myclass\com\mydomain\util
```

and manually copied the class files to util directory

and created a jar file myjar.jar of this format

```
H:\myclass>H:\graalvm\bin\jar tf myjar.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/mydomain/
com/mydomain/util/
com/mydomain/util/DBaccess.class
com/mydomain/util/Serial.class
```

I want **my source code JMainEntry.java to access the classes in the above jar file** myjar.jar.

JMainEntry.java

```
//Main Class of the Program

import com.mydomain.util.*;

public class JMainEntry 
{
    public static void main (String[] Args)
    {
        

        Serial myS = new Serial();
        myS.open();
        
        DBaccess myDB = new DBaccess();

        
        myDB.write();
        myDB.read();
    }
}
```

When i compile the code

```
H:\jar-compile>H:\graalvm\bin\javac -cp myjar.jar JMainEntry.java
```

I am getting the error

```
bad class file: myjar.jar(/com/mydomain/util/Serial.class)
    class file contains wrong class: Serial
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

[image]
I am not able to understand why javac is complaining like this,Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

> bad class file: myjar.jar(/com/mydomain/util/Serial.class)

Make sure you declare

```
package com.mydomain.util
```

at the top of all `.java` files in the directory `com/mydomain/util`, including `Serial.java`. To understand this better, read about packages.

Comment: Which one is the package name ,is it the whole string com.mydomain.util or just mydomain.util

Comment: It worked thanks

Comment: Is it possible to create a jar file without using a package declaration,just a flat file which contains just class files in this format .   jar tf myjar.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
DBaccess.class
Serial.class

Comment: I am getting this error when i try to run the class file after compilation. H:\graalvm\bin\java  JMainEntry
Error: Could not find or load main class JMainEntry
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mydomain/util/JMainEntry (wrong name: JMainEntry)

Comment: @Rahul.In Java requires that each .class file must be located in a directory which exactly matches the class’s declared package.

Comment: @Rahul.In "Is it possible to create a jar file without using a package declaration?" Yes, this is definitely possible. You will have to put all of your `.java` files in the root directory rather than in subdirectories. As I say in my question, you need to read about packages, including the default package, in order to figure this out.

Comment: @Rahul.In As for your other error, you should post a new question if you need help with that. I can't figure it out just from the error alone. Be sure to include the relevant code.